# Eclipse - C++ "Launch Failed"

Tags: c++

I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse for C/C++ yesterday and when I tried to run a program I got the following error:

> Launch failed. Binary not found.

I searched all over Google and tried the solutions posted, but still get the message. I've installed the JRE, I built the program before running, I set the binary parser to PE Windows, but I'm still getting the error.

All I have in the program is:

```
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

(I am barely starting to learn how to program and am reading C++ Primer 5th Edition which is where I got the lines above from)

Comment: If you just google `eclipse launch failed binary not found` you would get plenty of results. Do any of them help?

Comment: I did this and followed the solutions that people posted but I still get the error message

Comment: You simply need to setup a "Run Configuration" under `Run` in the menu bar.

Comment: @user3189177 I see. Putting what you have tried in your question would be helpful

Comment: @twj I did say what i have tried in the question above.

Comment: @NJMai this seemed to have worked, but now when I attempt to run through configuration, eclipse tells me that I have errors (but I don't see any, I may be wrong) so when I try running again, the launch failed message appears again. Forcing me to go through the configuration again.

Comment: @NJMai and I can't seem to find an EXE file. I can only find a CPP file and an H file.

Comment: Changing the run configurations seemed to have fixed the "Binary not found" issue, but now I get an issue where when I try to run the program, i get the following

Answer (score 1):

Well, to solve this standoff I realized the following:

1 - When you're creating a C + + project wizard now create an EXE with the name its first class (usually the name given to the project);

2 - Right click on the project RunAs-> Run Configurations;

3 - C / C + + Application New, Right Button;

4 - In C / C + + Application Click Browse, navigate to the folder of your project and select your EXE file and click Apply and Close;

5 - You can now click the Run.

Hope this helps, bye.